# How to display employee details along with sum(sal) of all employees?

Tags: mysql, sql, oracle, oracle-sqldeveloper, informatica-powercenter

Is it possible to display employee details like the below using SQL?

```
Emp_id, Emp_name, Emp_Sal, Sum(Emp_Sal)
```

Note: Here `Sum(Emp_Sal)` is total sum of all the employees.

Comment: Is the `Sum(Emp_Sal)` is for all the Employees? How the `Emp_Sal` is differ from `Sum(Emp_Sal)` for the individual employee?

Comment: yes .. I want to display total sal of all employees...

Comment: Can you give one example of your desired output.

Comment: Like I'm having 10 records in a table and I want to display employee details along with total salary for every record ....

Comment: So do you want a rolling sum for  salary ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Arulkumar offered a correct solution, using a scalar subquery.

The solution below uses an analytic function. Notice the windowing clause: it is empty, since we want a single group (all employees), so there is no "partition by", and we want to add all rows, so there is no "order by" (which by default means all rows are ordered as "equal" and we get the sum over all rows).

The advantage is that you only go through the base table once. In the "scalar subquery" method, the table is read twice. It may not matter in this simple example, but it may matter a lot in production, with very large tables.

```
    select empno, msal, sum(msal) over () as total_sal from employees;



     EMPNO       MSAL  TOTAL_SAL
---------- ---------- ----------
      7369        800      28875
      7499       1600      28875
      7521       1250      28875
      7566       2975      28875
      7654       1250      28875
      7698       2850      28875
      7782       2450      28875
      7788       3000      28875
      7839       5000      28875
      7844       1500      28875
      7876       1100      28875
      7900        800      28875
      7902       3000      28875
      7934       1300      28875
```

Answer (score 2):

You can get your expected result in this way:

```
SELECT Emp_id, Emp_name, Emp_Sal, (SELECT SUM(Emp_Sal) FROM Employee) AS TotalSalary
FROM Employee;
```

<kbd>[`Working DEMO`](http://rextester.com/NYWK40252)</kbd>

or

In a easy way store the SUM of the salary into a variable and use along with the `SELECT *,`

```
SELECT SUM(Emp_Sal) INTO @TotalSalary FROM Employee;

SELECT *, @TotalSalary AS TotalSalary
FROM Employee;
```

<kbd>[`Working DEMO`](http://rextester.com/WGAZH59319)</kbd>

Comment: @Marios I get the `SUM` value as a separate column with SELECT, so the GROUP BY is not needed for the SUM. Please check the [DEMO](http://rextester.com/NYWK40252)

Comment: This will produce a totalsalry column with a constant value for each record in emp table. I dont think this makes sense. Lets see whats the expected output from OP.

Comment: As i see,either is exactly what he wants or he doesn't speak good English :D

Comment: @Raj_Te: OP mentioned in the title and comments that he want all the employees salary

Comment: @KishoreKumar: You are welcome. In future if you post any question, kindly add some sample data and expected result. It helps the people to understand your exact issue and get proper response.